# How to generate a custom message (banner) on login my database

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I have 2 different environments for an oracle database. ( Example: Development environment & Test Environment ).

If i have logged into Development environment , a pop-up should be displayed saying " This is a development environment ".

Currently we have oracle database and we are using Toad/ Sql developer as a 3rd party tools to connect to that database.

Is there any way i can achieve and  create any popup like that ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use SEC_USER_UNAUTHORIZED_ACCESS_BANNER in the SQLNET.ORA on your database server.

OCI and SQLNet connections will show this when you connect

Here's SQL Developer when using a THICK connection:

[image]

Here is SQLPlus:

[image]

Here is my SQLNET.ORA and BANNER.TXT files:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But how can i test this methond of sql developer and unix in my desktop. Can you help me with some steps so that i will try now..

Comment: The docs for sqlnet.ora setting is here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF429

In SQL Developer, configure your connection for OCI or 'thick'

Comment: @ Is this like i have file called tnsnames.ora file . Can i add this message in that file ?

Comment: read my answer, read the link in the comment above, the message goes in a text file that you specify in sqlnet.ora on db server

Comment: Got it. As i have multiple environment. Can i give this message for a particular database. Example: I have 2 environments, Dev , Test. I want to specify it for only dev database. Is there any syntax i can get so that for a particular Host and service name i can mention this message.. ?

Comment: Is your ultimate end goal to identify which connections are dev (safe) and which are production (exercise caution)? If so, checkout connection colors. In Toad (and SQL Dev) you can assign a color to your connections. In Toad this is done via the login window and the color is prominently displayed in various areas (window border, session and window bar button border, status bar background color, etc). You could use green for dev and red for production, for instance. A message is a one time event whereas the color will follow you throughout your entire Toad session as a constant reminder.

Comment: you can have a specific message PER ORACLE_HOME and sqlnet.ora environment...I think

Comment: @MichaelS.. Thanks for the reply. Can you help me with some webpage link or steps in toad & Sql Developer which has all the steps to setup the color for my Dev & Production ( excercise )

Comment: Connections in SQLDev have a color property, you just need to pick a color